# Compact Framework Non Culture Specific Exception Messages

Tags: exception, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have created an application in Compact Framework 2.0

This application is being used in many various counties and cultures.

My Issue is that any and all exceptions are logged, but they are appearing in the culture of the device, in some cases this means i am unable to read them.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2004/08/06/210232.aspx) for details.

System.SR.dll assembly, which contains the error strings, is not present in the .NET CF redistributable, so you are probably logging a message that it says that a resource assembly isn't found (in a number of different languages). You could install the English assembly in users phones, but this is not recommended. You need to find a different debugging method and not rely on exception messages in users phones.